# Examine series for convergence $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}.\frac{\sqrt{n - 1}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem is the following: Examine the following series for convergence, absolute convergence or divergence.

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n - 1}.\frac{\sqrt{n - 1}}{n}$$

I knew I'd be using the Leibniz criterium. So I picked the sequence

$a_n := \frac{\sqrt{n - 1}}{n}$  with

$a_n \to 0 ~~(n \to \infty)$ (first requirement)

Furthermore $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = 1$, so we can't really conclude anything from that...

I must further prove that $a_n$ is monotonically falling, but that only applies for $n \ge 2$. Is it still applicable? Is the series still convergent according to Leibniz' criterium? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Gross evaluation: the terms are in $n^{-1/2}$ and when subtracted in pairs yield $n^{-3/2}$ and the series converges.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I didn't quite get what you meant by that... could you elaborate a bit more if convenient?

Comment: What do you mean with the line  after "Furthermore..." ? What does that have to do with anything related to Leibniz series?

Comment: @DonAntonio I read somewhere related to Leibniz' criterium, that there are cases to examine regarding the limit of the quotient of two consequent members... But that could've been Dalamber's criterium as well...

Comment: Mh, sorry, this is probably too technical for you. I have added an answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} a_n$ converges implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_n$ converges because the partial sum is just $$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^{n+1}a_n= a_1+\sum_{n=2}^N (-1)^{n+1} a_n$$ By the way $a_1=0$ so the two sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}a_n,\,\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}a_n$ are essentially the same.

Comment: Nice note, so we can at the end of the day conclude that the sequence is monotonically falling and converges to 0, so the series is also convergent? Neat. How would one examine for absolute convergence, I'm still a newbie...

Comment: The series is conditional convergent. When you take the absolute value of each term, you obtain a divergent series.

Comment: @imranfat What would be the way to prove it? Aka to prove that $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n - 1}}{n}$ diverges? The sequence inside converges monotonically to 0, but the series diverges. How do we prove that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @D.Petrov $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. If you're not yet comfortable with asymptotics, here you can use $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \geqslant \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geqslant 3$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot, that was fairly simple! So we can conclude, that if the sequences $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n}$ and the series of $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges by definition (harmonic series), so the series of $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n}$ must diverge as well. Right?

Comment: Right, @D.Petrov. If $0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant b_n$, then convergence of $\sum b_n$ implies convergence of $\sum a_n$, and by contrapositive divergence of $\sum a_n$ implies divergence of $\sum b_n$. Of course it's wildly different if the terms change sign.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the initial question but is provided on request of the OP.

$$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n}=n^{-1/2}\sqrt{1-n^{-1}}=n^{-1/2}\left(1-\frac{n^{-1}}2+o(n^{-1})\right)$$

and

$$\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}=n^{-1/2}(1+n^{-1})^{-1}=n^{-1/2}\left(1-n^{-1}+o(n^{-1})\right).$$

Then by subtraction (the series alternates),

$$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{n}-\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}=\frac{n^{-3/2}}2+o(n^{-3/2}).$$

This shows that the series converges, with an error of order $O(n^{-1/2})$ (by integration).